# python insert and update tstzranges with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Quick question about psycopg2 and ranges. Consider a postgresql table:

```
CREATE TABLE sensor(
  hostname varchar(64) NOT NULL, -- hostname of sensor
  ip varchar(15) NOT NULL,       -- ip of sensor
  period tstzrange NOT NULL,     -- valid range of sensor
  EXCLUDE USING gist (hostname WITH =, period with &&)
);
```

where the below insert works

```
sql = "insert into sensor values (%s,%s,%s);"
curs.execute(sql,(hostname,ip,'[%s,infinity]' % ts))
```

with hostname = socket.gethostname() ip='127.0.0.1' and ts is a isoformat timestamp i.e

```
dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time.time()).isoformat()+"z"
```

This works but is there an easier/better way to manipulate ranges in postgresql with psycopg2 other than python string formatting?

Additionally at some point I want to update the table with something like this

```
sql = "update sensor set period.upper = %s where hostname = %s and period.upper = infinity;"
```

I have not been able to find much documentation on psycopg2 support with ranges or perhaps I have not looked hard enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [range constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT) to create ranges from lower & upper bounds:

```
SELECT rangetype(lower, upper [, bounds]);
-- bounds can be '()', '(]', '[)' (default), or '[]'
```

For the update, you can use the `lower()` & `upper()` [range functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html).

```
sql = "insert into sensor values (%s, %s, tstzrange(%s, NULL));"
curs.execute(sql, (hostname, ip, ts))

sql = "update sensor set period = tstzrange(lower(period), %s) where hostname = %s and upper_inf(period);"
```

Note: I used [unbounded ranges](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INFINITE), which works with types too, where there aren't any *infinity* values.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are better ways, you havent searched enough: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#range-data-types